# CSS styling in PHP lost after "onclick" script — need help keeping HTML table with original CSS styling

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

When I click on one of the table headings which have an `onclick` function the CSS styling for the table disappears, i. e. it isn’t applied to the table any more. I tried altering the CSS file but I dont think I’m doing it right. I really need some help trying to figure out how to get the styling to remain the same.

```
<?php
$input = 'https://www.fdic.gov/bank/individual/failed/banklist.csv';

echo "<style>
  .parentTbl table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 0;
  width: 220px;
  table-layout: fixed
}

.childTbl table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: none; /* 1px solid #d7d7d7; */
  width: 219px;
  table-layout: fixed
}

.childTbl th, .childTbl td {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight:bold;
  background: #222937;
  color: white;
  width: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1pt solid red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.scrollData {
  width: 236px;
  height: 110px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

td.border{
  color: #D3AB04;
  font-size: 11px;
  width: 10px;
}

tr.row:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #222937;
}

tr.row:nth-child(even) {
  background: black;
}
</style>";

echo '<div class=parentTbl>';
  echo '<table>';
    echo '<tr>';
      echo '<td>';
        echo '<div class=childTbl>';
          echo '<table class=childTbl>';
            echo '<thead>';
              echo '<tr>';
                echo '<th onclick="sort_table(people, 0, asc1); asc1 *= -1; asc2 = 1; asc3 = 1; asc4 = 1;">Bank Name</th>';
                echo '<th onclick="sort_table(people, 1, asc2); asc2 *= -1; asc3 = 1; asc4 = 1; asc1 = 1;">City</th>';
                echo '<th onclick="sort_table(people, 2, asc3); asc3 *= -1; asc4 = 1; asc1 = 1; asc2 = 1;">Acq. Inst.</th>';
                echo '<th onclick="sort_table(people, 3, asc4); asc4 *= -1; asc1 = 1; asc2 = 1; asc3 = 1;">Closing Date</th>';
              echo '</tr>';
            echo '</thead>';
          echo '</table>';
        echo '</div>';
      echo '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';

    echo '<tr>';
      echo '<td>';
        echo '<div class=scrollData childTbl>';
          echo '<table>';
            echo '<tbody id=people>';

            if (false !== ($ih = fopen($input, 'r'))){
              fgetcsv($ih);
              while (false !== ($data = fgetcsv($ih))){
                $outputData = array($data[0], $data[1], $data[4], $data[5]);
                echo '<tr class=row>';

                foreach ($outputData as $row){
                  echo "<td class=border>" . htmlspecialchars($row) . "</td>";
                }

                echo '</tr>';
              }
            }

            echo '</tbody>';
          echo '</table>';
        echo '</div>';

        fclose($ih);

      echo '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
  echo '</table>';
echo '</div>';
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
var people, asc1 = 1,
  asc2 = 1,
  asc3 = 1;
asc4 = 1;

window.onload = function(){
  people = document.getElementById("people");
}

function sort_table(tbody, col, asc){
  var rows = tbody.rows,
    rlen = rows.length,
    arr = new Array(),
    i,
    j,
    cells,
    clen;
  // fill the array with values from the table
  for(i = 0; i < rlen; i++){
    cells = rows[i].cells;
    clen = cells.length;
    arr[i] = new Array();
    for(j = 0; j < clen; j++){
      arr[i][j] = cells[j].innerHTML;
    }
  }
  // sort the array by the specified column number (col) and order (asc)
  arr.sort(function(a, b){
    return (a[col] == b[col]) ? 0 : ((a[col] > b[col]) ? asc : -1*asc);
  });
  for(i = 0; i < rlen; i++){
    arr[i] = "<td>"+arr[i].join("</td><td>")+"</td>";
  }
  tbody.innerHTML = "<tr>"+arr.join("</tr><tr>")+"</tr>";
}
</script>
```

Comment: is that really the whole code? its missing basic html which could mess up the display

Comment: A few things that [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) says to your JS: `asc4` isn’t included in the `var` statement; `asc1`, `asc2`, `asc3` and `asc4` are never really used.

Comment: Works fine for me in http://phpfiddle.org/

Comment: It "messes" up when I click the headers to sort, I lose my CSS styling, colors, font sizes, etc... not sure why...

Comment: I loaded up the code and saw the problem.  It's a CSS issue for sure, and I'm guessing that it has to do with how you're defining and applying styles.  Respectfully, the structure is a bit of a mess, and I suspect that the browser is failing to apply the styles on reordering the rows because of that.  If you need to keep this structure, apply class names directly.  Don't use styles that are based on descendants.  I think you're giving the browser a headache.

Comment: Borrowed some of the code from here:  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/37632/how-should-i-sort-an-html-table-with-javascript-in-a-more-efficient-manner

Comment: @humble.rumble You need to set the JavaScript to be included in the `body` [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/m7ybkx3d/1/), not on page load (JSFiddle settings on the left). _Then_ it “messes up” the styles.

Comment: SeanOlson, thanks. Anyway, someone could clean things up? Its been a long while since I've coded... I really do appreciate the help. Thanks.

Comment: @humble.rumble Yes, I know but the JS was in the `body` of the OP’s code as well. It’s got a `window.onload` event which doesn’t fire a second time after an onload event.

Comment: @humble.rumble Sorting works for me when the JS is set to be included in the `body`.

Comment: Another problem solved by simply using debugging tools…

Comment: @humble.rumble I was talking about the settings on the left of the JSFiddle page (“Frameworks & Extensions”). The JS is “onLoad” but needs to be “No wrap - in `<body>`”.

Comment: @Kirk Please, ***do not*** edit your question to *fix* your code! That’s the answers’ job.

Comment: Oh, ok, sorry about that...

Comment: check this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28792885/losing-css-style-in-dynamically-added-table-rows

Answer (score 0):

This is your exact problem:

**Before the click:**

[image: Classes row and border are present.]

**After the click:**

[image: Classes disappeared!]

The `row` and `border` classes disappear because you aren’t generating them again in the sorting function.

I would suggest in the CSS to replace every occurence of

- `tr.row` with `.childTbl tbody>tr` (twice)
- `td.border` with `.childTbl tbody>tr>td`

and in the PHP code

- `echo '<tr class=row>';` with `echo '<tr>';`
- `echo "<td class=border>"`… with `echo '<td>'`…

You also have another error in assigning CSS classes to the wrapper `div`. Simply replace

- `echo '<div class=scrollData childTbl>';` with `echo '<div class="scrollData childTbl">';`

(There are similar and possibly better alternatives, too).

Comment: Thanks. Can you give me an example of how to do this? Its been a while since I've coded. This piece took me a while to figure out. Thanks.

Comment: I’ve updated the answer. Basically there are six replacements to make in your code, then it should work.

Comment: This deviates from my suggestion, but whatever floats your boat…

Answer (score -1):

Try to move css style codes out of PHP tags

```html
<style type="text/css">

.parentTbl table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 0;
  width: 220px;
  table-layout: fixed
}
.childTbl table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: none; /* 1px solid #d7d7d7; */
  width: 219px;
  table-layout: fixed
}
.childTbl th,
.childTbl td {  
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight:bold;
  background: #222937;
  color: white;  
  width: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1pt solid red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.scrollData {
  width: 236px;
  height: 110px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

td.border{
  color: #D3AB04;
  font-size: 11px;
  width: 10px;
}

tr.row:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #222937;
}

tr.row:nth-child(even) {
    background: black;
}

</style>

<?php 


$input = 'https://www.fdic.gov/bank/individual/failed/banklist.csv';

echo '<div class=parentTbl>';
 echo '<table>';
  echo '<tr>';
   echo '<td>';
    echo '<div class=childTbl>';
     echo '<table class=childTbl>';
     echo '<thead>';
      echo '<tr>';
        echo '<th onclick="sort_table(people, 0, asc1); asc1 *= -1; asc2 = 1; asc3 = 1; asc4 = 1;">Bank Name</th>';
        echo '<th onclick="sort_table(people, 1, asc2); asc2 *= -1; asc3 = 1; asc4 = 1; asc1 = 1;">City</th>';
        echo '<th onclick="sort_table(people, 2, asc3); asc3 *= -1; asc4 = 1; asc1 = 1; asc2 = 1;">Acq. Inst.</th>';
        echo '<th onclick="sort_table(people, 3, asc4); asc4 *= -1; asc1 = 1; asc2 = 1; asc3 = 1;">Closing Date</th>';
     echo '</tr>';
     echo '</thead>';
    echo '</table>';
   echo '</div>';
  echo '</td>';
 echo '</tr>';

echo '<tr>';
 echo '<td>';
  echo '<div class=scrollData childTbl>';
   echo '<table>';      
    echo '<tbody id=people>';

if (false !== ($ih = fopen($input, 'r'))) 
{
fgetcsv($ih);
    while (false !== ($data = fgetcsv($ih))) 
    {    
        $outputData = array($data[0], $data[1], $data[4], $data[5]); 


              echo '<tr class=row>';

                foreach ($outputData as $row)
                {
                    echo "<td class=border>" . htmlspecialchars($row) . "</td>";        

                }   

              echo '</tr>';         

    }

}
   echo '</tbody>';
   echo '</table>';
  echo '</div>'; 

fclose($ih);

echo '</td>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '</table>';
echo '</div>';

?>

<script type="text/javascript">
        var people, asc1 = 1,
            asc2 = 1,
            asc3 = 1;
            asc4=1;
        window.onload = function () {
            people = document.getElementById("people");
        }

function sort_table(tbody, col, asc){
    var rows = tbody.rows, rlen = rows.length, arr = new Array(), i, j, cells, clen;
    // fill the array with values from the table
    for(i = 0; i < rlen; i++){
    cells = rows[i].cells;
    clen = cells.length;
    arr[i] = new Array();
        for(j = 0; j < clen; j++){
        arr[i][j] = cells[j].innerHTML;
        }
    }
    // sort the array by the specified column number (col) and order (asc)
    arr.sort(function(a, b){
        return (a[col] == b[col]) ? 0 : ((a[col] > b[col]) ? asc : -1*asc);
    });
    for(i = 0; i < rlen; i++){
        arr[i] = "<td>"+arr[i].join("</td><td>")+"</td>";
    }
    tbody.innerHTML = "<tr>"+arr.join("</tr><tr>")+"</tr>";
}
    </script>
```

Comment: Zero difference to the browser